# FBML document.getElementById(‘’).setTextValue issue

Tags: facebook, forms, fbml, fbjs

I just added a FBML application to my fan page but I can't make JS to work ... though I read the FBJS best practices ... I guess I am missing something.

here is the current code :

```
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">

<input type="text" name="email" id="emailInput" onclick="document.getElementById(‘emailInput’).setTextValue(‘Hi!’);" value="votre adresse email" alt="Entrez votre email" />
<input type="hidden" name="place" value="facebook" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitInput" value="" alt="Valider" />

</form>
```

The onclick event seems not to work but I can't get any answers from my research over Internet ...

Any help welcome ;)

Cheers guys.

Gotye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebug or Chrome tools to verify that the id is actually emailInput, and that the Facebook FBML parser didn't append a prefix to the ID.  But FBML pages have been deprecated so you will be better off switching to an iframe fan page so you aren't running the risk of having Facebook kill your FBML fan page.  Also, javascript is a ton easier in iframe pages and can be called without having to wait for a click event to fire.